# Function like USE to point to a SQL database on a different server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server, you can apply the `use` function to point a query to another database.  For example:

`USE databasename
GO;`

Is there a function that allows you to point to a different database server and use a database on that server?  I would expect this to work, but no luck:

`USE [servername].databasename
GO;`

I know I could just point the query to the database on the other server, but when I am dealing with production versus staging environments, it's more efficient to declare the server and database in the beginning of the query.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't use a linked server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use Linked Servers to accomplish this. I don't know if this will meet your needs, however.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

In Management Studio, this is available under Database/Server Objects/Linked Servers.

You can refer to objects on this server like this:

```
[Server].database.schema.object
```

I just realized this isn't what you want. JonH has it right, you can't specify a dabase on another server at the beginning of your query.

Answer (score 7):

`USE` does not span across to another server, you need to define a linked server on your local instance and then you can access data from that server.