# Query database running on another physical SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

Historically we have a product which installed two databases on the same server. There is an custom application which assumes that both databases are on the same server.

In a new version they have split the databases onto two separate servers and obviously now the custom application is giving the error:

> Database 'DB_2' does not exist. Make sure that the
>   name is entered correctly.

Is there anything I can do in the SQL Server setup so that the application is still able to query the `DB_2` database without modifying the custom application?

The query being used is structured as follows:

```
Use DB_2 

SELECT * FROM MyUser.MyTable
```

Comment: you can probably use replication to get a copy of the relevant tables in DB_2 from one server to the other, but a better solution would be to modify the software to connect to both servers.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for the suggestion but this wouldnt be an option.

Comment: Probably not possible, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228985/function-like-use-to-point-to-a-sql-database-on-a-different-server

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `linked Server`, then `Create` a `Database DB_2` add a `Synonym` for different objects. something like below.

```
use master
GO;
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'RemoteServer', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'
GO
CREATE DATABASE [DB_2];
GO
USE [DB_2]
GO
CREATE SYNONYM [MyUser].[MyTable] FOR [RemoteServer].[db].[MyUser].[MyTable]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Linked Servers** feature. In SSMS go to **Server Object/Linked Servers** folder in Object Explorer. And link second server. So you can query another DB using this `SELECT * FROM [Linked_Server_Name].[Database_Name].[Schema_Name].[Table_Name]`

Comment: This would still require me to edit the query in the custom software. Is there any way to get this Linked Servers to work without requiring the entry of a Linked Server name?

Comment: I think you can try to play with aliases. Something useful may be [here](http://alexpinsker.blogspot.ru/2007/08/how-to-give-alias-to-sql-linked-server.html)

Comment: Here is helpful [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050331/sql-server-linked-database-aliases) .